# Python unpack string in to array

Tags: python, arrays, string

I am working with Ruby every day, but i have an issue in Python. I was found this languages very similar... But I have some problems with migration from Ruby :)

Please, help me to convert this action in python:

```
   string = "qwerty2012"
   (var, some_var, another_var)  = string.unpack("a1a4a*")
```

this should return three variables with unpacked values from string:

```
   var         = "q"      # a1
   some_var    = "wert"   # a4
   another_var = "y2012"  # a*
```

Help me to represent it in Python
Thank you!

Comment: You probably don't want to name a variable `string`

Comment: Actually, `string` is fine. The type in Python is `str`.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi, yeah, but there's also the string module, and we don't know if OP is importing it, so assigning `string` to something new would take it out of the namespace. Kind of bad practice.

Comment: @Chinmay But there's still the `string` package - but yes it's probably not especially problematic.

Comment: For some reason, I thought the module was called `strings`. Guess that says something about how often I find myself using it. Yeah, not a great idea to name something the same as a standard module.

Comment: struct module does unpacking but doesn't support arbitrary length structures, slicing is best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = "qwerty2012"
var, some_var, another_var = s[:1], s[1:5], s[5:]
```

will do the assignment and yield respectively:

```
q
wert
y2012
```

The above assignment makes use of *slice notation* as described by the [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html). This SO post [Good Primer for Python Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1209279) gives a good explanation too.

Answer (score 9):

```
s = "qwerty2012"
(a, b, c) = s[:1], s[1:5], s[5:]
```

Comment: Levon, sorry for it. You are be the first! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Python does have a similar module named [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html).  It lacks the ability to *grab the rest of the string* in the same way that [Ruby and PHP lifted from Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html).  You can almost get there though:

```
>>> import struct
>>> s = 'qwerty2012'
>>> struct.unpack_from('1s4s', s)
('q', 'wert')
>>> def my_unpack(format, packed_string):
...    result = []
...    result.extend(struct.unpack_from(format, packed_string))
...    chars_gobbled = struct.calcsize(format)
...    rest = packed_string[chars_gobbled:]
...    if rest:
...        result.append(rest)
...    return result
...
>>> my_unpack('1s4s', 'qwerty2012')
['q', 'wert', 'y2012']
>>> my_unpack('1s4s', 'qwert')
['q', 'wert']
>>> [hex(x) for x in my_unpack('<I', '\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF')]
['0xefbeadde']
```

I wish that the `struct` module implemented the rest of Perl's `unpack` and `pack` since they were incredibly useful functions for ripping apart binary packets but alas.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a preliminary recreation of `unpack`:

```
import re
import StringIO

def unpack(s, fmt):
    fs = StringIO.StringIO(s)
    res = []
    for do,num in unpack.pattern.findall(fmt):
        if num == '*':
            num = len(s)
        elif num == '':
            num = 1
        else:
            num = int(num)
        this = unpack.types[do](num, fs)
        if this is not None:
            res.append(this)
    return res

unpack.types = {
    '@': lambda n,s: s.seek(n),             # skip to offset
    'a': lambda n,s: s.read(n),             # string
    'A': lambda n,s: s.read(n).rstrip(),    # string, right-trimmed
    'b': lambda n,s: bin(reduce(lambda x,y:256*x+ord(y), s.read(n), 0))[2:].zfill(8*n)[::-1],   # binary, LSB first
    'B': lambda n,s: bin(reduce(lambda x,y:256*x+ord(y), s.read(n), 0))[2:].zfill(8*n)          # binary, MSB first
}
unpack.pattern = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z@](?:_|!|<|>|!<|!>|0|))(\d+|\*|)')
```

It works for your given example,

```
unpack("qwerty2012", "a1a4a*")  # -> ['q', 'wert', 'y2012']
```

but has a long list of datatypes not yet implemented (see [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-unpack)).

Answer (score 1):

This might ease your migration from Ruby:

```
import re
import struct

def unpack(format, a_string):
    pattern = r'''a(\*|\d+)\s*'''
    widths = [int(w) if w is not '*' else 0 for w in re.findall(pattern, format)]
    if not widths[-1]: widths[-1] = len(a_string) - sum(widths)
    fmt = ''.join('%ds' % f for f in widths)
    return struct.unpack_from(fmt, a_string)

(var, some_var, another_var) = unpack('a1a4a*', 'qwerty2012')  # also 'a1 a4 a*' OK
print (var, some_var, another_var)
```

Output:

```
('q', 'wert', 'y2012')
```